# JButton orientation within a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am designing a GUI for an image editor in which I have multiple buttons which apply different effects to the selected image.  Currently I have the Display button in the top center of the window, the Load button in the bottom center of the window, and I want the effect buttons stacked on the left side of the window.  Here is the image of my GUI, with the `ButtonPanel` `JPanel` in red, the `FileChooser` `JPanel` in green, and the `ImageDisplay` `JPanel` in blue:

[image: test]

As you can see, the buttons in the `ButtonPanel` are stacking horizontally instead of vertically.  I would like them to stack vertically.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: It looks like you're asking this before reading up on use of layout managers -- why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the buttons in the ButtonPanel are stacking horizontally instead of vertically. I would like them to stack vertically.

The default layout for a JPanel is a FlowLayout which displays all components horizontally.

Use a different Layout Manager. Maybe a `GridLayout`. With a `GridLayout` you can display components vertically if you set the constructor parameters properly.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 2):

> the buttons in the ButtonPanel are stacking horizontally instead of vertically. I would like them to stack vertically.

You can try with [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) as well that allows multiple components to be laid out either vertically or horizontally.

Please have a look at [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) where you will find the [sample code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BoxLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BoxLayoutDemo.java) as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a `JToolBar` (kind of like in PhotoShop) where you can change the orientation or float the tool bar around. See more at [How to Use Tool bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)

[image: tool bar with top orientation]
[image: tool bar with side orientation]
[image: tool bar floating]