# How can I display button in vertical orientation?

Tags: java, awt

I am working on a layout that is set to use **`Class ComponentOrientation`**. That displays all the button from `LEFT_TO_RIGHT` and `RIGHT_TO_LEFT`. In short, buttons are displaying in Horizontal orientation. I want to display buttons in a vertical orientation. So far, I researched that `ComponentOrientation` comes with fields `LEFT_TO_RIGHT`, `RIGHT_TO_LEFT` and `Unknown`, but all the fields are displaying component in a horizontal orientation. Is there any way to display button in verticle orientation using Class `ComponentOrientaion`?

Comment: Do you mean a set of buttons each with horizontal text, laid out vertically one on top of the other ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I need vertical orientation for button only.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726935/jbutton-orientation-within-a-jpanel

Comment: Currently, I am using a Card layout, when I am trying to use Box layout or Grid Bag Layout. Nothing is showing up in the respected Jpanel. Is there are any change I can do? So far, As per my understanding, Japnel is set for Card layout and Buttons inside are using ComponentOrientation Class.

Comment: formatting done

Comment: Please post [mcve] : "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I replaced `ComponentOrientation` with `Jtable`. I am able to control the layout with tables easily.